# how to compile a lua excutable?

Tags: lua

I'm playing with lua with the following link: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/lua/lua_basic_syntax.htm.
Now I'm a bit confused with this supposed simple task to run lua file in the other way, i.e.,

> Let's try another way to execute a Lua program. Below is the modified test.lua file *−
>   Live Demo*
>
> ```lua
> #!/usr/local/bin/lua
>
> print("test")
> ```
>
> Here, we have assumed that you have Lua interpreter available in your `/usr/local/bin` directory. The first line is ignored by the interpreter, if it starts with `#` sign. Now, try to run this program as follows −
>
> ```sh
> chmod a+rx test.lua
> ./test.lua
> ```
>
> We will get the following output.
>
> ```
> test
> ```

I think somehow I need to know where the Lua interpreter located. Any comments are greatly appreciated.

**EDIT:** After changing `/usr/local/bin/lua` into `/usr/bin/lua`, it worked out well.

Comment: On what system are you? Have installed Lua? https://www.lua.org/download.html

Comment: Ubuntu 18, yes. I have installed Lua.

Comment: What is the output of `$ which lua` on your machine?

Comment: the output is: /usr/bin/lua

Comment: Thank you for the hint. It worked out now. Cheers.

Comment: The title does not really reflect the question.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the [manual](https://www.lua.org/manual/5.3/manual.html#7), use

```
#!/usr/bin/env lua
```

if lua is in your `PATH`.